# MNIST generalisation to european digit handwriting

Tags: python, keras, mnist

I want to use the MNIST dataset to teach my neural network to recognise numbers. My problem is: The data I am working with is "european". What i mean by that is: the seven always has a dash (it often has a dash in MNIST too so that is more unlikely to cause a problem) and more importantly: the 1 is always written with this hook in Europe, whereas Americans tend to use a straight line (almost 100% of MNIST 1s are a straight line).
So it seems to me that training on MNIST can cause problems. Have you ever ran into that problem? And if so, how did you solve it? I haven't found good solutions online.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is very broad for stackoverflow, as it doesn't relate directly to programming. I would recommend asking on https://datascience.stackexchange.com since that site is more geared toward theory and best practices

Comment: I’ve trained mnist with a small amount of data augmentation, it has worked pretty well for generalization. I’ve also used a kmeans classifier and that worked pretty well for European digits too: https://www.geraldsai.com/2018/09/28/taking-a-nearest-neighbour-approach-to-number-recognition/#more

Comment: The MNIST dataset is a academic benchmark dataset, it is not meant to train a production handwritten digit recognition system.

Comment: Thanks to you all. It is good to know that it is not too much of an issue. To find out how much of a problem it really is, i will head over to stackexchange datascience. Also: What is the proper way to get data for such a project? Are there any for free online?